# oc logs -p => how to enable storage of previous logs?

Tags: logging, kubernetes, openshift

In a OpenShift cluster, while debugging a frequently restarting pod, I get this behaviour:

```
> oc logs -p mystuff
Error from server (BadRequest): previous terminated container "mystuff" in pod "mystuff-1" not found
```

What do I have to do to tell OpenShift/Kubernetes to store the previous logs?

Comment: If the pod is crashing on start and it is deployed through a deployment config, better to use ``oc debug dc/yourappname``. This will create a debug pod where you will be at the shell. You can then run the startup command ``oc debug`` displays you manually and see what goes wrong, and otherwise debug things.

Comment: No, it's not crashing at startup, but sometime later (like 10-30 minutes after starting and working fine for a while).

Comment: What OpenShift installation is this? Your own? OpenShift Online? Minishift?

Comment: Also make sure you have correct ``oc`` client version that corresponds to the version of the OpenShift cluster.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton, it's an on-premise OC of our customers.

Comment: How about ``oc`` client version? If for example ``oc`` 3.6 was used with 3.7 cluster, you can have some issues in some corner cases. So always important to use the correct version.